# How to add import content of a hyperlink to the title of that hyperlink with Regex?

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this link (HTML Links - Hyperlinks)

```
<p class="mb-40px"><a href="my-name-is-prince.html"></a></p>
```

I want to import the content from link, copy it, and put it again in front of `</a>` ?

The Output should be:

```
<p class="mb-40px"><a href="my-name-is-prince.html">My Name Is Prince</a></p>
```

My regex is almost good, can copy the link from o place to another, but I don't know how to get off the connecting line

FIND: `(<p class="mb-40px"><a href=")(.*?)(.html">)(</a>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\2\3\u\2\4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such job can be done with PythonScript plugin in Notepad++

---

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example format.py):

```python
import re

def format(match):
    lab = re.sub('-', ' ',match.group(2)).title()
    return match.group(1) + lab

editor.rereplace('(<p class="mb-40px"><a href="(.*?)\.html">)', format)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> format)
- Done

**Result for given example:**

```
<p class="mb-40px"><a href="my-name-is-prince.html">My Name Is Prince</a></p>
```

Comment: It works. Super answer, @Toto.  You always have best answers. THANKS !

Answer (score 1):

My solution consists of two steps:

Step 1:

- **Find**: `(<p class="mb-40px"><a href=")(.*?)(.html">)(</a>)`
- **Replace By**: `\1\2\3\u\2\4`

Step 2.

- **Find**: `(?-s)(\G(?!^)|html">)((?!</a).)*?\K[-]`
- **Replace By**: `\x20`